# scala: akka clustering not working - actors don't start

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

This is how the actor section in my application.conf looks like -

```
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    unstarted-push-timeout = 100s
    default-mailbox {
      mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.SingleConsumerOnlyUnboundedMailbox"
      mailbox-push-timeout-time = 2s
    }
    default-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "fork-join-executor"
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 16
        parallelism-factor = 4.0
        parallelism-max = 64
      }
      throughput = 1
    }
    job-manager-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "fork-join-executor"
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 16
        parallelism-factor = 4.0
        parallelism-max = 64
      }
      throughput = 1
    }
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      port = 2557
    }
  }
  extensions = [
    "akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubExtension"
  ]
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://dispatcher@0.0.0.0:2557"
    ]
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
  }
}

akka.contrib.cluster.pub-sub {
  name = dispatcherPubSubMediator
  role = ""
  routing-logic = round-robin
  gossip-interval = 1s
  removed-time-to-live = 120s
}
```

This is how I create actors -

```
val aRef = instances match {
      case 1 =>
        system.actorOf(Props[T].withDispatcher(dispatcher), name)
      case _ =>
        system.actorOf(
          ClusterRouterPool(AdaptiveLoadBalancingPool(
            SystemLoadAverageMetricsSelector), ClusterRouterPoolSettings(
            totalInstances = instances * 64, maxInstancesPerNode = instances,
            allowLocalRoutees = isLocal, useRole = None)
        ).props(Props[T]).withDispatcher(dispatcher), name)
    }
    ClusterReceptionistExtension(system).registerService(aRef)
```

The single instance (local) creation works fine. But the cluster pool instantiation is not working (no exception/error, but constructor/preStart etc are not called.

Any help appreciated.